# $z^{-1}$ and Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

The complex analysis book I'm reading claims that the function $f(z)=z^{-1}$, $z \in \Omega := \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$ and the curve $\gamma=e^{it}$ , $t \in [0,2\pi]$, provide an example where the Cauchy Integral Formula "fails to apply", in the sense that $f(z)$ is not equal to $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$ for $z$ with $0<|z|<1$. While the reason for this non-applicability is, of course, that $\gamma$ wraps around the singularity at $0$, my book does not do the calculations proving that the integral formula fails.

However, it should be enough to show that for some (or any) $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with  $0<|z|<1$, the integral 
$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{w(w-z)}dw$ is not equal to $\frac {2\pi i}{z}$. As I'm out of shape evaluating complex line integral, I'm asking for help computing the integral in question.

Update: I think I came up with an easy solution, see below.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Apply residue theorem, the poles of the function $f(w)=\frac{1}{w(w-z)}$ are $w=0$ and $w=z$, and since $|z|<1$ you have that $z$ is inside the contour of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{1}{w(w-z)} = \frac{1}{z} (\frac{1}{w-z}-\frac{1}{w})$ we get 
$$\int_{|w| = 1}\frac{1}{w(w-z)}dw = $$
$$\frac{1}{z}\Bigg(\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{w-z}dw - \int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{w-0}dw\Bigg)$$ 
Both integrals on the right hand side equals $2\pi i$ by Cauchy's integral formula. Hence the integral on the left hand side equals $0$.